# MVC 4 System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unhandled-exception

Currently having some trouble when running my web app. I go to run it followed by it hitting an unhandled exception.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'.

```
Line 42:             catch (Exception ex)
Line 43:             {
Line 44:                 throw ex;
Line 45:             }
Line 46:             finally
```

Here's my Web.Config Connection string as well.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source= \SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=aspnet-MvcApplication5-20130311122440;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication5-20130311122440.mdf" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is actually `Initial Catalog` <-- notice the space

Comment: Thank you! Although now it's giving me the same thing with 'attachdbfilename'